# Initialization of Variables in C++

Tags: c++, initialization

Now from my knowledge what I know is that you should always set your integers to a specific value because they will be assigned garbage values by the compiler. Now I was using a program and initialized an array of strings and was wondering is it the same case with std::strings. Are they assigned some garbage value too? What about other primitive types? And is this with only primitive types like int, long, char. Also if you have an object with a std::string, int etc member variables; are they assigned garbage values too? (I'm working on C++).

Plus is it the same with other programming languages?

Comment: What do you mean by "strings"?

Comment: std::strings. Sorry should have mentioned that. :(

Comment: No problem. Then the current answer is correct. Note `std::string` is not a primitive type.

Comment: I know that. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a class, in general (but not always, anyone can write a weird class) you can assume its default constructor sets it up to a default initial state. Read the class's spec to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are [strings] assigned some garbage value too? What about other primitive types?

String of C++ Standard Library (i.e. `std::string`) is *not* a primitive type. Unlike primitive types, it has a constructor, which will be invoked when you do not specify any value.

Primitive types like `int`, `long`, `char`, on the other hand, remain uninitialized, unless you provide an explicit initializer, or place them in static memory (in which case they are zero-initialized).

Answer (score 3):

std::string's default constructor, "Constructs an empty string, with a length of zero characters."

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

If you have an object (class) with a mix of primitives and non-primitives, the default constructors of the non-primitives are called, and the primitives behave just like the would if they were not members of a class. That is, you'll need to initialize them (in the object's constructor, preferably with an initialization list). (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: I was going to say this, but because of the way he talks about "primitive types", I think he is talking about something like `const char* someString;`.

Comment: I meant primitive data types and data types like std::strings too. What will be the case in const char* someString.

Comment: I think he's asking about the difference between an object like a string and C++'s primitive types. The primitives always need initialization except for some cases where they're declared as static.

Comment: Ron, const char * someString is just a pointer. Like other pointers it's default value will be something which is not meaningful to you.

Comment: Whatever happens to be at the memory address the pointer is pointing at. :) Garbage if it hasn't been initialized.

Pointers should really never be uninitialized. If at the time of creation you don't have an object to point a pointer at, initialize it with nullptr. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Answer (score 1):

All "primitive types" (int, double, float, pointers (including pointers to char)) are uninitialised, unless they are statics.   So are arrays of "primitive types".     That means they all potentially contain "garbage values".

The `std::string` type in the standard library is a (templated) class type that, when default constructed, is initialised to the empty string in all circumstances.

The rules for struct and class types are a bit more complicated but, in simple terms, the initialisation depends on workings of the relevant constructor.